# Load different xib files on Orientation in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, orientation, xib

I have created two `.xib` file one for portrait mode and other for landscape mode,

on each rotation i want to load respective `.xib` file,

Here is my code snippet,

**ViewAppDelegate.m class**

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

    if ([UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation==UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait | [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation==UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)
    {
        self.viewController = [[OrientationViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"PortraitController" bundle:nil];
        UINavigationController *navigationController=[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.viewController];
        self.window.rootViewController = navigationController;
    }
    else{
        self.viewController = [[OrientationViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LandscapeController" bundle:nil];
        UINavigationController *navigationController=[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.viewController];
        self.window.rootViewController = navigationController;
    }

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

**ViewController.m class**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation{
    return YES;
}


-(void)viewWillLayoutSubviews{

    if ([UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation==UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait | [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation==UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown) 
    {
        [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"PortraitController" owner:self options:nil];
    }
    else{
        [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"LandscapeController" owner:self options:nil];
    }

}
```

After writing this much of code my app shows nothing.. it shows only black screen.

***please suggest some solution.***

Comment: what happend the code which is  place in viewWillLayoutSubviews kept in shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation?

Comment: it doesn't show black screen, it loads xib file of portrait mode, it doesn't load xib file of landscape when i rotate it to landscape..

Comment: are you connect the files owner for LandscapeController?

Comment: yes for both the xib... i connected file owner with Viewcontrollers file.

Comment: once check with breakpoints is that method correctly working or not?

Comment: in app delegate check this conditon and load that one     UIDeviceOrientation orientation = [UIDevice currentDevice].orientation;

Comment: keep UIDeviceOrientation orientation = [UIDevice currentDevice].orientation;
    if (orientation == UIDeviceOrientationPortrait || orientation == UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown) {this condition and load according to that one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

once try like this

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(changeOrientation) name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification object:nil];
```

add this method into the app view controller for getting notification.

```
-(void)changeOrientation {
    UIDeviceOrientation orientation = [UIDevice currentDevice].orientation;
    if (orientation == UIDeviceOrientationPortrait || orientation == UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown) {
        [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"Portrait" owner:self options:nil];
    }
    else {
        [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"Landscape" owner:self options:nil];
    }

}
```

Comment: Nice it is working.. but when i launch my application in portrait mode it loads xib file of landscape not of portrait.. i wrote first two line which u suggested in `viewWillAppear` method

Answer (score 2):

you can use `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation` in viewController.m to achieve this goal

```
-(void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation  duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
    if( UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(toInterfaceOrientation) )
    {
        [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@-landscape", NSStringFromClass([self class])]
                                      owner: self
                                    options: nil];
        [self viewDidLoad];
    }
    else
    {
        [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", NSStringFromClass([self class])]
                                      owner: self
                                    options: nil];
        [self viewDidLoad];
    }
}
```

you can check orientation on your `viewwillAppear` method like below and load xibs respectively:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewWillAppear:YES];

    if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(self.interfaceOrientation)){
        [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", NSStringFromClass([self class])]
                                      owner: self
                                    options: nil];
        [self viewDidLoad];
    }
    else
    {
        [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@-landscape", NSStringFromClass([self class])]
                                      owner: self
                                    options: nil];
        [self viewDidLoad];
    }
}
```

Here, I have name xibs like 

Portrait: viewControllerName
Landscape: viewControllerName-landscape

and I have again called viewDidload method to load new xib again.

Another way to Achieve this is:
[GPOrientationKit](http://logisian.blogspot.in/2012/08/support-landscape-and-portrait-using.html)
It is also a nice one!!

Or,

You can create change frame of your controls on rotating by creating 2 xibs with all controls having same tag name and make one `LayoutManager class` to map the tags and fetch frames and assign respective landscape/portrait frames(by fetching from xibs).

Comment: it is working.. but when i launch my application in portrait mode it loads xib file of landscape not of portrait.

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)setFramesForPotrait
{

// set frames here

}

-(void)setFramesForLandscaeMode
{

// set frames here

}

-(bool)shouldAutorotate.....
{
return Yes
}

-()willAutoRotate......
{
if(orientation = uiinterfaceOrientationPotrait)
{
[self setFramesForPotrait];
}
else
{
[self setFramesForLandscape];
}
```

Why don't u set frames for both landscape and portrait in single view controller

Comment: ya u do it using xib but then in code u put the frame for landscape and portrait